# Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm trying to create a link to redirect to Contact.
Component

```
    <aura:attribute name="Contacts" type="Contact[]"/>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.Contacts}" var="con">
<tr>
<td><a onclick="{!c.navigateToRecord}" style="width:100%;">{!con.Name}</a></td>
<td> {!con.Email} </td>
<td> {!con.Contact_level__c} </td>
<td> {!con.Account.Name} </td>
<td> {!con.Owner.Name} </td>
<td> {!con.CreatedBy.Name} </td>
<td> {!con.CreatedDate} </td>
```

Controller

```
navigateToRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
     var navEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
     navEvent.setParams({
          recordId: component.get("v.contact").Id,
          slideDevName: "detail"
     });
     Console.log("hey");
     navEvent.fire();
```

I get this Message

```
Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined
```

Help me PLS, WHY?

Answer (score 1):

This means that force:navigateToSObject is not supported in your current code. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToSObject/documentation) states:

> This event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in Lightning Experience, the Salesforce app, and Lightning communities.

If you're using something else, like Lightning Out, you need to use a different syntax, such as window.location.

Comment: What am I suppose to do to deal with it?

Comment: @AndreyBeloborodov It depends on the context. If the event is null, that means that you need to sforce.one (if available) or window.location.

Comment: I'm in lightning, I don't understand what does it mean =(

Comment: @AndreyBeloborodov There's things like Lightning Out, etc. Without knowing more about the code is running, I don't have a specific answer. The point is, you only get this event if you're actually in Lightning.